# ExtJs visual designer in visual studio 2010

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Is there any way to use ExtJs.Net in visual studio 2010 at design time - because you have to write it in html not drag and drop manner (button can be dragged and dropped, but window or panel cannot be edited its content)?

Comment: Yo can try: http://netjswire.codeplex.com/ in a very short future it will be updated to decouple design time from code generation and it will be compatible with SharpKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to have a look at 'Ext Designer', this allows you to do a lot of the GUI work in it's own application.

Last time I looked it didn't do the whole kit and kaboodle (you still have to write your event handler methods outside of this) but I believe this has now been implemented.

You will still need to take the JS code from designer and pop it into VS2010, but it may give you more of the WYSIWYG drag drop interface stuff you're looking for:

http://www.sencha.com/products/designer

Comment: But there isn't a full integration in the designer of visual studio 2010, right?

Comment: No, it's a seperate application, but it may enable you to get the drag drop GUI design you're after, then when you're happy with the layout you can dump it into VS2010 to add the server side code.